# Can't add a system email in Acumatica (GMail / organization)

Tags: acumatica

I have successfully added one Account to Acumatica and had no issues, however I went back to add a support email and I am getting a `"Mail receive failed.
USER BAD Unknown command s20mb273724509pao"` I have validated the user and password by logging into Gmail via the browser and everything there works fine.

POP and IMAP are enabled and as stated I have one successful email already configured using the same settings (different user obviously)

Comment: Ok edited the server settings (995) and (587) and am now recieving the following error

`Mail receive failed.
-ERR [AUTH] Web login required: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I got it, Acumatica is considered a less secure app make sure you are logged into the browser as the email account you wish to add to Acumatica and complete the following steps.

1. In the top right corner select "My Account"
   2.Click on the connected sites and apps link in the first box on the left
2. Toggle the allow less secure apps.
3. Open the champagne and do a little dance